SELunix Unable to open logfile- permission denied
My conntrackd service is failing to start with the error (message logs):
Jun 25 15:01:19 ip-10-0-10-231 conntrackd[30874]: ERROR: can't open logfile `/var/log/binu/conntrackd-stats.log'.Reason: Permission denied
Jun 25 15:01:19 ip-10-0-10-231 systemd[1]: conntrackd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 25 15:01:19 ip-10-0-10-231 systemd[1]: conntrackd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 25 15:01:19 ip-10-0-10-231 audit[1]: SERVICE_STOP pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 msg='unit=conntrackd comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'

Checking the status:
$ systemctl status conntrackd.service
× conntrackd.service - connection tracking daemon for debugging and High Availablity
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/conntrackd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-06-25 15:01:19 UTC; 6min ago
   Duration: 10ms
    Process: 30873 ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/lock/conntrack.lock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 30874 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/conntrackd -C /etc/conntrackd/conntrackd.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 30874 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    CPU: 6ms

Jun 25 15:01:19 direct.systest systemd[1]: Starting conntrackd.service - connection tracking daemon for debugging and High Availablity...
Jun 25 15:01:19 direct.systest systemd[1]: Started conntrackd.service - connection tracking daemon for debugging and High Availablity.
Jun 25 15:01:19 direct.systest conntrackd[30874]: ERROR: can't open logfile `/var/log/binu/conntrackd-stats.log'.Reason: Permission denied
Jun 25 15:01:19 direct.systest systemd[1]: conntrackd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 25 15:01:19 direct.systest systemd[1]: conntrackd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

The permission of the conntrackd is:
$ ls -lZ /usr/sbin/conntrackd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root system_u:object_r:conntrackd_exec_t:s0 238544 Jan 30  2023 /usr/sbin/conntrackd

The service is supposed to create the file /var/log/binu/conntrackd-stats.log and that is not being created due to permission issues.
I have other logs in the same folder from different processes
Can someone help me fix the permission of the folder so conntrackd can create the file?
Update 1:
Service starts when selinux is off and creates the file:
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root system_u:object_r:conntrackd_log_t:s0 5746 Jun 26 07:55 /var/log/binu/conntrackd-stats.log

As asked:
$ systemctl cat conntrackd
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/conntrackd.service
[Unit]
Description=connection tracking daemon for debugging and High Availablity
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
# rhbz#1255578 daemon will not start if lock file is left dangling
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -f /var/lock/conntrack.lock
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/conntrackd -C /etc/conntrackd/conntrackd.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Permission of the files in the folder /var/log/binu:
$ ls -lZ /var/log | grep binu
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 binu   users           unconfined_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0         102 Jun 26 08:07 binu
$
$ ls -lZ /var/log/binu
total 192
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0    2922 Jun 25 04:14 binu.log
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0    2282 Jun 25 04:14 config.json
-rw-r-----+ 1 root root system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   11333 Jun 25 04:16 instance_init
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root system_u:object_r:cron_log_t:s0 167670 Jun 26 08:05 monitor.log
-rw-r--r--+ 1 root root system_u:object_r:cron_log_t:s0   3215 Jun 26 00:00 refresh_users


If you think it is SELinux, you can temporary disable it, just to check if that solves it.
Before disabling and enabling check if SELinux is actually in Enforced mode:
getenforce.
To temporary disable:
setenforce 0
Test it, then enable again:
setenforce 1
If that doesn't solve it, you know it is not SELinux.
In that case please provide the output of:

systemctl cat conntrackd
ls -lash /var/log/binu


thanks @C-nan your suggestion helped, I have updated the question. how do I solve it now? what is the permission that the folder /var/log/binu would need?

At this moment I don't have a system to reproduce the situation, but you can try to set the var_log_t context: semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t '/var/log/binu(/.*)?' and restorecon -R /var/log/binu. If that doesn't solve it try with conntrackd_log_t context, if that doesn't solve it, figure out what context it needs ausearch -m avc -c conntrackd | audit2why

Thanks @C-nan ausearch helped
